# Grouping by maximum timestamp in an ArrayList for attributed ID

Tags: java, sorting

I have an arraylist that consists of an object that consists of a number of ID's and it's attributed timestamps. There are multiple id's with different timestamps in the arraylist. i would like to get the maximum timestamp for each id. how can i go about doing this?

I Created the following function for sorting:

```
public Map<Integer,Date> getMaximumDateForId(Session session) throws ParseException {
    Map<Integer,Date> mapIdDate = new HashMap<Integer,Date>();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    List<CSVServiceBaseFormat>  listOfRemovedEntitlements = getListOfServiceProviderId(session);
        for(CSVServiceBaseFormat record : listOfRemovedEntitlements){
            if(!mapIdDate.containsKey(record.getBbd_id())){
                    mapIdDate.put(Integer.parseInt(record.getBbd_id()),formatter.parse(record.getActivity_date()));

            }else{
                if((mapIdDate.get(formatter.parse(record.getActivity_date()))).before(formatter.parse(record.getActivity_date()))){
                    mapIdDate.put(Integer.parseInt(record.getBbd_id()),formatter.parse(record.getActivity_date()));
                }
            }
        }
        return mapIdDate;
}
```

Comment: It would be best to share a minimal example of the structure and what you have tried so far. But conceptually, you loop through the list keeping track of the id and the maximum time stamp. Tactically, you can use loops or streams.

Comment: Are you asking about a List of Lists?

Comment: post an example of the object you're describing.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the structure i am describing: https://imgur.com/a/vsMrL9Y

Comment: List<CSVServiceBaseFormat> cList = new ArrayList<>(); 

cList contains duplicate id's and an attributed timestamp. i would like to store the maximum timestamp with the associated id.

Comment: no one has ever tried to sort a data structure before and I'm sure it can't be googled...

Comment: @jordaniac89 what?

Comment: The comment by @jordaniac89 must have been ironic, Raz88. *Very* ironic.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated along with `Date`, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). For your question, two options come to mind: code an algorithm with a loop or use streams. At first glance it would seem that your code is already doing the job, so if it isn’t, you need to describe the problem with it. Please be precise about the difference between expected and observed behaviour.

Comment: Yes, it was sarcasm. If you have an object, have it implement the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, then sort them, then get the first one in the collection. Done.

Answer (score 1):

For the example I am assuming the following class.

```
public class Activity {

    int id;
    LocalDate date;

    // constructor, getters, toString method

}
```

To get the latest date for each ID:

```
    List<Activity> elements = // …
    Map<Integer, LocalDate> latestDates = elements.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Activity::getId, 
                    Collectors.mapping(Activity::getDate,
                            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.maxBy(LocalDate::compareTo), 
                                    Optional::get))));
```

I tried the code with the following list:

```
 4 2018-03-07
 3 2018-03-14
 4 2018-02-11
 3 2018-02-18
 1 2018-01-24
 2 2018-01-02
 5 2018-03-13
 4 2017-10-01
 5 2018-01-09
 3 2017-10-11
```

The resulting map printed as:

> {1=2018-01-24, 2=2018-01-02, 3=2018-03-14, 4=2018-03-07, 5=2018-03-13}

If you find the stream code too hard to follow, use a loop instead.

Edit: my previous stream expression was:

```
    Map<Integer, LocalDate> latestDates = elements.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Activity::getId, 
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Activity::getDate)), 
                            optAct -> optAct.get().getDate())));
```

Even though the old one is a line shorter, I consider the new one more natural in that it maps `Activity objects to dates before finding the latest date (rather than the other way around). If you need the activities (not only the dates), the old expression will be a better starting point.